# MATLAB does not know the function 'equilibrate'

Tags: function, matlab

I have a 2 line MATLAB script. It gives me error “Undefined function or variable 'equilibrate'”. It runs in my professors Mac but not in my laptop.

Why am I getting this error?

Equilibrate by default should generate P, R and C matrices.

```
A=magic(5)
[P,R,C]=equilibrate(A)
```

Comment: Please post the complete error.

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'equilibrate'. My filename is scaling.   

Error in scaling (line 3)
[P,R,C]=equilibrate(A)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? `equilibrate()` was introduced in 2019a.

Comment: I agree, it has to be an earlier MATLAB version: upgrade MATLAB.

Comment: write `which equilibrate `. It should return a path, otherwise you either dont have it defined (see @beaker comment) or you have to add it to your path (very weird and remote option since it should be on the default one, but you never know )

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Now it works after upgrade